# Java Image Writing

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I want to create thousands of dynamic images with Java. I've created a JFrame and a LayeredPane and put a JLabel on this. Then I am writing image contents in this JLabel. Then I create this image of this LayeredPane like this

```
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)comp.createImage(width, hight);
```

It creates the image perfectly but its size is 20KB (more or less). Can I reduce the image size without losing its quality. I have just text and colour in JLabel.

OR

Is there another way to create images based on Text?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce its size *on disk* by saving as JPEG and reducing the Q. This has least impact on quality. Resampling has major impact.

Comment: So it is the size on disk that matters, rather than the size in memory?

Answer (score 0):

For Text-only images containing only a little number of colors, storing them as GIF files (with a palette of only 2 or 3 colors) could be a lot smaller that JPEG, which is optimized for storing full-color pictures. I would start fiddling around with Paint.NET or some other tool to find out what's possible and which format is the best, before programming the Image-to-file-encoding.